# Как сделать два списка с одинаковым классом, с помощью одной функции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

http://www.scribbletribe.com/tutorials/styling-the-select/demo-2.html

Вот значит есть список, естественно, стилизировал я уже его под себя. Работает все замечательно и, что хорошо - в старых браузерах тоже. Но есть одно но - никак не могу сделать два списка в передах одной формы с разным содержимым.
Т.е.:

```
<form action="#">
    <select class="turnintodropdown" id="1" name="1">
        <option>11111111111111</option>
        <option>11111111111111</option>
        <option>11111111111111</option>
        <option>11111111111111</option>
        <option>11111111111111</option>
    </select>  
    <select class="turnintodropdown" id="2" name="2">
        <option>22222222222222</option>
        <option>22222222222222</option>
        <option>22222222222222</option>
        <option>22222222222222</option>
        <option>22222222222222</option>
    </select> 
 </form>
```

```js
function tamingselect()
{
 if(!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode){return;}

// Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
 var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
 var ts_listclass='turnintoselect';  // class to identify ULs
 var ts_boxclass='dropcontainer';   // parent element
 var ts_triggeron='activetrigger';   // class for the active trigger link
 var ts_triggeroff='trigger';   // class for the inactive trigger link
 var ts_dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
 var ts_dropdownopen='dropdownvisible'; // open dropdown
/*
 Turn all selects into DOM dropdowns
*/
 var count=0;
 var toreplace=new Array();
 var sels=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for(var i=0;i<sels.length;i++){
  if (ts_check(sels[i],ts_selectclass))
  {
   var hiddenfield=document.createElement('input');
   hiddenfield.name=sels[i].name;
   hiddenfield.type='hidden';
   hiddenfield.id=sels[i].id;
   hiddenfield.value=sels[i].options[0].value;
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield,sels[i])
   var trigger=document.createElement('a');
   ts_addclass(trigger,ts_triggeroff);
   trigger.href='#';
   trigger.onclick=function(){
    ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
    ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
    return false;
   }
   trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger,sels[i]);
   var replaceUL=document.createElement('ul');
   for(var j=0;j<sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length;j++)
   {
    var newli=document.createElement('li');
    var newa=document.createElement('a');
    newli.v=sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
    newli.elm=hiddenfield;
    newli.istrigger=trigger;
    newa.href='#';
    newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
    sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
    newli.onclick=function(){
     this.elm.value=this.v;
     ts_swapclass(this.istrigger,ts_triggeron,ts_triggeroff);
     ts_swapclass(this.parentNode,ts_dropdownopen,ts_dropdownclosed)
     this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue=this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
     return false;
    }
    newli.appendChild(newa);
    replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
   }
   ts_addclass(replaceUL,ts_dropdownclosed);
   var div=document.createElement('div');
   div.appendChild(replaceUL);
   ts_addclass(div,ts_boxclass);
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div,sels[i])
   toreplace[count]=sels[i];
   count++;
  }
 }

/*
 Turn all ULs with the class defined above into dropdown navigations
*/

 var uls=document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++)
 {
  if(ts_check(uls[i],ts_listclass))
  {
   var newform=document.createElement('form');
   var newselect=document.createElement('select');
   for(j=0;j<uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length;j++)
   {
    var newopt=document.createElement('option');
    newopt.value=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href;
    newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML));
    newselect.appendChild(newopt);
   }
   newselect.onchange=function()
   {
    window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   }
   newform.appendChild(newselect);
   uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform,uls[i]);
   toreplace[count]=uls[i];
   count++;
  }
 }
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
 }
 function ts_check(o,c)
 {
   return new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(o.className);
 }
 function ts_swapclass(o,c1,c2)
 {
  var cn=o.className
  o.className=!ts_check(o,c1)?cn.replace(c2,c1):cn.replace(c1,c2);
 }
 function ts_addclass(o,c)
 {
  if(!ts_check(o,c)){o.className+=o.className==''?c:' '+c;}
 }
}

window.onload=function()
{
 tamingselect();
 // add more functions if necessary
}
```

Второй список стилизируется но не работает вообще. В чем проблема?
(Вопрос про javascript часть, с css разобраться в моих силах)

Comment: так `class` разные сделайте и уже к разным классам разыне стили приписывайте.

Comment: проблема не в стилях, а в javascript, он их не воспринимает, как только нажимаешь на один из блоков открывается лишь только первый список, второй при этом не активен

Comment: вообще-то у них там два списка на разных страницах, а не два списка на одной. Если Вы переключаетесь между списками - URL меняется. Поэтому у них и стили разные.

Comment: Я, видимо, не совсем доступно пояснил, за что прошу прощения. При помещении двух списков на одной странице, работает лишь один из них. Собственно, проблема в этом и заключается

Comment: т.е. второй даже не выпадает? или при нажатии на второй выпадает первый?

Comment: При нажатии на второй выпадает первый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ищется только первый выпадающий список **ul**.

```
ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
```

Вот измененный вариант, где каждому созданному элементу навешивается уникальный **id**.

```
var replaceUL = document.createElement('ul');
replaceUL.id = "ul-"+sels[i].id;
```

В дальнейшем, при нажатии из атрибута ссылки берется i**d** списка, к которому принадлежит ссылка, поиск элемента производится по этому **id**.

```
trigger.onclick=function(){
  ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
  /// Поиск
  ts_swapclass(document.getElementById( (this.hash).split('#')[1] ),ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
  /// Поиск
  return false;
}
```

```js
function tamingselect() {
  if (!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode) {
    return;
  }

  // Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
  var ts_selectclass = 'turnintodropdown'; // class to identify selects
  var ts_listclass = 'turnintoselect'; // class to identify ULs
  var ts_boxclass = 'dropcontainer'; // parent element
  var ts_triggeron = 'activetrigger'; // class for the active trigger link
  var ts_triggeroff = 'trigger'; // class for the inactive trigger link
  var ts_dropdownclosed = 'dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
  var ts_dropdownopen = 'dropdownvisible'; // open dropdown
  /*
   Turn all selects into DOM dropdowns
  */
  var count = 0;
  var toreplace = new Array();
  var sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < sels.length; i++) {
    if (ts_check(sels[i], ts_selectclass)) {
      var hiddenfield = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenfield.name = sels[i].name;
      hiddenfield.type = 'hidden';
      hiddenfield.id = sels[i].id;
      hiddenfield.value = sels[i].options[0].value;
      sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield, sels[i])
      var trigger = document.createElement('a');
      ts_addclass(trigger, ts_triggeroff);
      trigger.href = '#ul-' + sels[i].id;
      trigger.onclick = function() {
        ts_swapclass(this, ts_triggeroff, ts_triggeron)
        ts_swapclass(document.getElementById((this.hash).split('#')[1]), ts_dropdownclosed, ts_dropdownopen);
        return false;
      }
      trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
      sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger, sels[i]);
      var replaceUL = document.createElement('ul');
      replaceUL.id = "ul-" + sels[i].id;
      for (var j = 0; j < sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length; j++) {
        var newli = document.createElement('li');
        var newa = document.createElement('a');
        newli.v = sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
        newli.elm = hiddenfield;
        newli.istrigger = trigger;
        newa.href = '#';
        newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
          sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
        newli.onclick = function() {
          this.elm.value = this.v;
          ts_swapclass(this.istrigger, ts_triggeron, ts_triggeroff);
          ts_swapclass(this.parentNode, ts_dropdownopen, ts_dropdownclosed)
          this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue = this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
          return false;
        }
        newli.appendChild(newa);
        replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
      }
      ts_addclass(replaceUL, ts_dropdownclosed);
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(replaceUL);
      ts_addclass(div, ts_boxclass);
      sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, sels[i])
      toreplace[count] = sels[i];
      count++;
    }
  }

  /*
   Turn all ULs with the class defined above into dropdown navigations
  */

  var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
    if (ts_check(uls[i], ts_listclass)) {
      var newform = document.createElement('form');
      var newselect = document.createElement('select');
      for (j = 0; j < uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length; j++) {
        var newopt = document.createElement('option');
        newopt.value = uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href;
        newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML));
        newselect.appendChild(newopt);
      }
      newselect.onchange = function() {
        window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
      }
      newform.appendChild(newselect);
      uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform, uls[i]);
      toreplace[count] = uls[i];
      count++;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
  }

  function ts_check(o, c) {
    return new RegExp('\\b' + c + '\\b').test(o.className);
  }

  function ts_swapclass(o, c1, c2) {
    var cn = o.className
    o.className = !ts_check(o, c1) ? cn.replace(c2, c1) : cn.replace(c1, c2);
  }

  function ts_addclass(o, c) {
    if (!ts_check(o, c)) {
      o.className += o.className == '' ? c : ' ' + c;
    }
  }
}

//window.onload=function()
//{
tamingselect();

// add more functions if necessary
//}
```

```css
<!--////////////////////////////////////////
////           Demo #1              ////
////////////////////////////////////////
--> .dropcontainer {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #777;
}
.trigger {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff url(../images/select-arrow-open.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.trigger:hover {
  color: #777;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-open.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
.activetrigger {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.activetrigger:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  color: #777;
}
.activetrigger:active {
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  color: #777;
}
.dropcontainer ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropcontainer ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  outline: none;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dropdownhidden {
  display: none;
}
.dropdownvisible {
  height: auto;
}
<!--////////////////////////////////////////
////           Demo #2              ////
////////////////////////////////////////
--> .dropcontainer_demo2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #777;
}
.trigger_demo2 {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff url(../images/select-arrow-open.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.trigger_demo2:hover {
  color: #777;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-open.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
.activetrigger_demo2 {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.activetrigger_demo2:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  color: #777;
}
.activetrigger_demo2:active {
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/select-arrow-close.png) 98% center no-repeat;
  color: #777;
}
.dropcontainer_demo2 ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropcontainer_demo2 ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.dropcontainer_demo2 ul li:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  outline: none;
}
.dropcontainer_demo2 ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.dropcontainer_demo2 ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dropdownhidden_demo2 {
  display: none;
}
.dropdownvisible_demo2 {
  height: auto;
}
.dropdownvisible_demo2 {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <select class="turnintodropdown" id="1" name="1">
    <option>11111111111111</option>
    <option>11111111111111</option>
    <option>11111111111111</option>
    <option>11111111111111</option>
    <option>11111111111111</option>
  </select>
  <select class="turnintodropdown" id="2" name="2">
    <option>22222222222222</option>
    <option>22222222222222</option>
    <option>22222222222222</option>
    <option>22222222222222</option>
    <option>22222222222222</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Объясните тупому человеку как это все должно вместе смотреться и куда его вставлять, пожалуйста) тупой, каюсь

Comment: @drewkrit Просто замените всю функцию  tamingselect()

Comment: не могу понять, у меня по какой то причине не форматируются они вообще и выглядят дефолтно, вам не трудно на фидл залить?

Comment: на кодпин http://codepen.io/Vitaliiy/pen/epMJgZ

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Плагин, который Вы нашли, не применение различных стилей, но с одним `JS` функционалом.

Если вы сравните JS (http://www.scribbletribe.com/tutorials/styling-the-select/js/select.js) и тот же путь но `select_demo2.js`, Вы увидите, что они отличаются только первыми строчками - где классы прописаны.

В Вашем случае несколько вариантов.

1. искать другой плагин, чтобы поддерживал несколько разностилевых списков на странице
2. исправить их код: сделать самому на их основе
3. самый грязный вариант - запускать их код для разных классов столько раз, сколько у вас стилизованных списков...